# Are design questions (with actual code) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Suppose I'm working on a particular module in my software.  I have a proposed design (possibly already implemented or prototyped) that I want feedback on in a *tangible format*, such as a Java `interface`, an XML schema, or a URL structure for a website.  What I'm *not* referring to is pseudocode and a list of design pattern words.  **Are questions about proposed designs that are specified in code on-topic?**

Comment: I believe the conclusion is that if you only have interfaces, that's not on-topic on Code Review, but if you have interfaces and an implementation to go with it, then both the interfaces and the implementation can be reviewed.

Comment: @SimonForsberg What precedent is there for that, if I may ask?

Comment: See http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2308/31562 , and http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2335/31562 . There was a whole chat room created for discussing this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16508/code-review-discussion-about-help-vs-review